# Как сохранить пользователя после закрытия браузера?

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте, когда логиню пользователя функцией
`Yii::$app->user->login($user,$duration);` Он удаляется после закрытия браузера.  Как мне сохранить пользователя в куках чтобы я мог восстановить его после открытия браузера

Comment: Документация говорит, что именно этот код устанавливает хранение и в сессии, и в куках. Второй параметр как раз для этого. Подробнее опишите ситуацию и побольше кода тоже желательно.

Answer (score 1):

`Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), 3600 * 24 * 30);`

Если же у вас стандартная форма входа из advanced приложения(или аналогичная, где в модели есть свойство rememberMe) рекомендую так:

`Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);`

Comment: Возможно у вас какой-то не верный конфиг. Прикрепите его к вопросу (все конфиг)